# SQL: How to string together multiple queries using an inner join?

Tags: php, mysql, search, phpmyadmin

I'm designing a search engine which will sift through data in a database. I have 2 tables in my database:

```
Members:= `MemberID|Firstname|Secondname|Member_Type|Skills|Marital Status`
Schedule:= `ScheduleID|MemberID (foreign key)|six_am|seven_am|...|nine_pm`
```

(where the values for six_am|seven_am|...|nine_pm are boolean values and represent availablity)

My question is if there's a way to create a single SQL query similar to:

`SELECT * FROM members1 (WHERE $x LIKE $firstname OR $x LIKE SecondName...) INNER JOIN schedules ON (members1.members_id = schedules.member_id) 
WHERE eleven_am=1 OR twelve_pm=1`

This way, I can enter a single query instead of multiple ones.

Comment: First, use prepared statements to bind your variables to your sql, which will help you prevent SQL injection. Second, please provide more details, the desired result is unclear. Also, a better way to build your query is `SELECT
 *
FROM
 members1
 inner join schedules on members1.members_id = schedules.member_id
WHERE
 $x LIKE $firstname OR $x LIKE SecondName
 AND eleven_am=1 OR twelve_pm=1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use prepared statements:

```
SET @query = 'build your own query in any way';
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
SET @id = 4; -- here you can add variable for safe inserting to the query. if you want to
EXECUTE prepared_query USING @id;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The `@query` can be built by some server side language (PHP for example) or by string manipulations in pure SQL.
Afterwards you send the "template" to execution.
If you'll provide more details I can build more exact example.
But this is an idea.